# The property 'xyz' does not exist on value of [imported] type 'xyz' in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I am accessing functions of an imported nodejs module in typescript, and the compiler spews the given error for each method call or property access. This is my declaration:

```
 import imageProc = module('imageProc');
```

Where `imageProc` is a compiled C++ node module with no typescript definitions.

And this is my call:

```
 var result:NodeBuffer = imageProc.blur(input, 5, 15, 8);
```

Is there a way to:

1. strongly type the imageProc var and define the methods it provides, or
2. disable the error for the imageProc var

Compilation works fine, however the said error populates the error log making it difficult to separate legitimate errors from false positives.

I'm using VS 2012 with Web Essential 2012 and TypeScript 0.9.0.1.

Comment: So far all of the other "duplicate" questions ONLY resolve the error by strongly typing the methods/props. This is difficult as I do not know how to strongly type imported C++ modules, do not know how to mark an imported module as "dynamic", and do not know how to disable the error for a specific var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can, the very first thing you should do is update your TypeScript package, as 0.9 is very outdated.

---

Without getting too complicated, defining `imageProc` as `any` will have TS ignore the type.

```
var imageProc: any = require('imageProc');
```

---

Another way is to create a placeholder definition file.

Create a file named `imageProc.d.ts` with:

```
declare var imageProc: any;
declare module "imageProc" {
    export = imageProc;
}
```

Then you would import it as:

```
import imageProc = require('imageProc');
```

Or with ES6 syntax like:

```
import * as imageProc from 'imageProc';
```

Comment: Does not work with TypeScript 0.9. I cannot use a "var" with a "require" on the same line. I need to use the "import" keyword,

Comment: I tested it again with `0.9.0.1`, it works for me. What error is it giving you?